# Input value for search filter disappears in Select ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using `Ant Design` in my React app.

In my Select Component I set showSearch to true.

```
<Select
    showSearch={true}
    mode="multiple"
    ...
```

Input value for search disappears after I selected one of the options. I'd like to search/filter e.g. `London` and be able to click several options at one search.

How can I do it?

Comment: give us the code

Answer (score 0):

There is `open` prop to control this feature.

> `open` Controlled open state of dropdown `boolean`

```
<Select
    open={someVariable}
    showSearch={true}
    mode="multiple"
    ...
```

source: [antd documentation](https://ant.design/components/select/)